# Display after closing and opening the laptop

Tags: display

After closing my laptop and opening, I'm getting this:

[image: screenshot]

I can move my cursor, but there is no reaction to the keys.

Comment: yiou can see your cursor? Which Ubuntu version do you run?

Comment: Are you able to change to another TTY and back again? I note you say there's no reaction to the keys.
Is it Gnome, KDE or something else?
You can enable Ctrl-Alt-Backspace for restarting x, but again you mention there's no response to the keys.

Comment: @damadam i can see my cursor and i'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: @edooze it's GNOME, i tried to press many keys, but helps only reboot the system with power button.